# iCloud intermittently freaks out, "has wrong magic" lines appear in log

Tags: ios, synchronization, icloud

Whilst testing iCloud integration in one of my apps, I occasionally find that changes do not propegate between devices and the log of all devices is littered with lines in the format of:

```
// device 1 log
Aug 14 19:18:56 unknown ubd[3585] <Warning>: Unknown error: 316: attr blob @ 0x2a7710 has wrong magic (0x00000000 != 0x41545452)
// device 2 log
Aug 14 19:19:06 unknown ubd[99] <Warning>: Unknown error: 316: attr blob @ 0x2b8240 has wrong magic (0x00000101 != 0x41545452)
// device 3 log
Aug 14 19:19:24 unknown ubd[1328] <Warning>: Unknown error: 316: attr blob @ 0xed7c0b0 has wrong magic (0xc0ed7bdb != 0x41545452)
```

It seems that `ubd` is the Ubiquity daemon which powers iCloud and presumably the `blob` is related to the document I'm trying to sync, but `magic`?

To be clear, iCloud syncing in this app typically does work (and DropBox sync is rock solid). This problem is just an occasional phase. I haven't quite nailed down what causes it to occur or disappear yet.

The question, in short, is: what is this `magic`, is it important that it is 'wrong' and has anyone else had experience with this issue?